# Matplotlib: Looking up which subplots contains BarContainer

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write an autolabel function as the one here (https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html), and it looks like the following:

```
def autolabel(barContainer):
"""
Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
"""

for rect, yerr in zip(barContainer, barContainer.errorbar.get_children()[0].get_segments()):
    error  = yerr[1,1]- yerr[:,1].mean() # print error
    height = rect.get_height()

    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            '{:.1f} +/- {:.1f}'.format(height, error),
            family="monospace",
            ha='center', va='bottom')
```

However, when I call the function using a different subplot (let's say it's called ax2), I get a NameError. I would like to be able to lookup the ax on which my BarContainer is located, without explicitly passing ax=ax2 in my function.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You need to pass the axes in as an argument _to_ the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to modify the function content itself, you just need to add an additional argument that the function accepts. This argument should be the *axes*:

```
def autolabel(barContainer, ax):

    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """

    for rect, yerr in zip(barContainer, barContainer.errorbar.get_children()[0].get_segments()):
        error  = yerr[1,1]- yerr[:,1].mean() # print error
        height = rect.get_height()

        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '{:.1f} +/- {:.1f}'.format(height, error),
                family="monospace",
                ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Then, when you want to call the function:

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
# Some plotting with ax
autolabel(barContainer, ax)

# Some plotting with ax2
autolabel(barContainer, ax2)
```